# Show and hide a component based on a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a loading icon component, which simply displays a spinner while loading something. I load it into my Sign In component, and wish to display the icon once the user clicks the Login button (And the API call is busy).

So:

```
import Loading from '../common/loading';
```

I then set an isLoading variable, defaulted to false:

```
this.isLoading = false;
```

Then, within my render method, I wish to determin if I need to show the spinner or not.

```
render() {

  var LoadingSpinner = this.state.canLogin ? Loading : '<div></div>';
```

This fails.

And then my button is where I show the spinner. I'm hoping to hide the 'Sign In' text, and replace it with the spinner, but ... first thing is to handle the spinner, based on the isLoading variable.

```
 <button 
              className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
              type="button" 
              onClick={this.handleSignin} 
              disabled={!this.state.canLogin}>
                <span>Sign in</span> <LoadingSpinner />
              </button>
          </div>
```

Can/should this be done this way, OR... should I maybe pass a prop to my Loading component, called 'Visible' or something, and I set that?

Answer (score 0):

put isLoading to constructor with default false
and then inside the render method, just add a condition

```
{ this.state.canLogin ? <LoadingSpinner /> : null }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do, using a state variable.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    }
  }
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {this.state.loading && <div>Loading</div>}
          <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click to Load</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
</div>
```